# swift - Enviar json body pelo alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

Eu estou no meu primeiro projeto em Swift, e preciso enviar um `RequestBody` no POST pelo Alamofire.

Esse é o um exemplo de JSON que preciso enviar:

```
{
"user":{
    "email":"fulano@yopmail.com"
 }
}
```

E eu tenho minha Class `User`.

```
 func toDictionary() -> [String:Any]
{
    var dictionary = [String:Any]()

    if email != nil{
        dictionary["email"] = email
    }

    return dictionary
}
```

Eu estou usando o `SwiftyJSON` para fazer o parse.
Minha dúvida é basicamente como eu consigo transformar o meu objeto, nessa estrutura de JSON que eu preciso e enviar pelo Alamofire como POST.

Answer (score 0):

O Alamofire permite enviar um dicionario como parametros de um POST:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://myserver.com", parameters: User.toDictionary(), encoding: .JSON)
.responseJSON { request, response, JSON, error in
    print(response)
    print(JSON)
    print(error)
}
```